# SQL Server with bulk update avoiding Cursor

Tags: sql-server, performance, cursor, updating

I have a performance problem with cursor which I would like to avoid. 
The problem I am trying to solve is:
To update a column (VARCHAR ) on each record (about 6000000) (by using one update statement) in the Main table by using a result calculated by a UDF which itself should update a counter in another Counter table.
- The problem is that the UDF can not update Countertable because it is a side effect. 
- It also can not update a temp or variable table because of READONLY flag.
- I used an update trigger on the main table, but the trigger fired once by a single update statement which stored in a table called inserted.

The solution I have opted to is to use the Cursor as follows.

1. Create a cursor from the Main table.
2. fetch the first row
3. get the counter from the Counter table
4. counter++
5. call a PROC to calculate the result , counter, etc
6. update the Main table with the result from the PROC
7. update the Counter table
8. fetch another row

But believe me it is too slow about 125 hours (no way).

Can any one out there help me?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What are your table structures, what are you trying to update?

Comment: I am counting the main table records in the counter table and then store that counter in the main table. thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing the counter in main table?

Comment: It shows the order of row. The counters are the dates and it show the order in that year.

Comment: +1 tombom. In general - don't store in the db what you can calculate from what's already stored (in a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: Otherwise I have to find the count by using select then update, which is slower than having counters.

Comment: I think it would be best if you show us the table structure, some sample data and explain in more detail what you are trying to do, what that function calculates and so on. Then I'm sure we can find a way to speed things up.

Comment: OK, The counter table consists of two cols (Yeart int ,Countert int)
the main table have the (sex int, dob date, code varchar,etc ).
Now I want to store in the main table's col code the sex and the counter of the year of birth (order of this person in this year).  Then will increase the countert col in the counter table.    
Hope this will help.

Comment: Assume we have (sex=1,dob='2003-01-02',code='') in the main table and (yeart = 2003, countert=10) in the counter table.  Then after update, the main table will have (sex=1,dob='2003-01-02',code='1200311') and in the counter table (yeart = 2003,countert=11). for all records in the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have another column in your main table which identifies the row, or else the counter wouldn't make much sense.

Can you try with this? If I understood your problem right, neither a function nor a cursor is needed. Just a temporary table, cause you can't read and update a table at the same time.

```
INSERT INTO tmpTable
SELECT
yourPrimaryKey, sex, YEAR(dob) AS dobyear, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(dob) ORDER BY dob) AS counter
FROM
mainTable;

UPDATE mainTable
SET code = CONCAT(tmpTable.sex, tmpTable.dobyear, counter)
FROM
mainTable
INNER JOIN tmpTable
ON mainTable.yourPrimaryKey = tmpTable.yourPrimaryKey;
```

It's not tested, excuse any syntax errors or whatever.